# How to get child classes with prefix packages using reflection classloading from deployment folder in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, urlclassloader, classloading

Tried below code but it's giving zero results (subTypesOf size is zero).

```
 File projectFolder = new File("project_folder_some_path");
 final Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<>();
        Files.walkFileTree(projectFolder.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (file.toString().endsWith(".class")) {
                    urls.add(file.toFile().toURI().toURL());
                }
                return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
            }
        });

        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[0]), getClass().getClassLoader());
        ConfigurationBuilder configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .addClassLoader(classLoader)
                .addUrls(urls)
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage("com.comp"));
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configuration);
        Set<Class<?>> subTypesOf = (Set<Class<?>>) reflections.getSubTypesOf(classLoader.loadClass("com.comp.framework.bean.SuperNumeratorIdEntity"));
// subTypesOf  size is zero
        classLoader.close();
```

**here *subTypesOf* size is zero. But the class files are present in project folder which extends com.comp.framework.bean.SuperNumeratorIdEntity**

The class i am looking for looks like this:
*public class XyzEntity extends SuperNumeratorIdEntity*

Answer (score 0):

Are classes in typical folder hierarchy? then your URL should refer to that folder, not to each .class file in it. And end with `/` to give java information that it should expect a folder here:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///c:/projects/myProject/bin/")}, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: did you try without filterInputsBy? and you can load classes without any issues from this class loader?

Comment: Yes, classes are in deployment folder hierarchy. I tried adding / with the no result.  Variables holding data lokks like this. Urls are loaded correctly. Just FYI urls = {HashSet@4572}  size = 14236
 0 = {URL@4590} "file:/C:/APP-INF/classes/com/comp/interfaces/common/ivo/claim/PaymentReserveCoverDistributionIVO.class"
 1 = {URL@4591} "file:/C:/APP-INF/classes/com/comp/claim/server/jdo/business/bean/ClaimTransactionExcessJDOBean.class"

Comment: @Raushan but why you have urls to each class, it should work just fine, and even better with just url to `file:/C:/APP-INF/classes/`